# Delay when using setTitle on UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, title

I am playing around with a custom keyboard and I'm having a problem when I am trying to change the title of my buttons.

This is the function that I am calling when a specific button is tapped, as you can see I am trying to change both the title as well as the outputText (a variable I declared) on some buttons.

```
func numericsSelected() {

if button01.titleForState(.Normal) == "Q"   {

        button01.outputText = "1"
        button01.setTitle("1", forState: .Normal) // This causes a delay
        button02.outputText = "2"
        button02.setTitle("2", forState: .Normal)
        button03.outputText = "3"
        button03.setTitle("3", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

There are no problems when changing the outputText variable, however, when my numericsSelected() function is called I am experiencing a 1 second delay before setTitle takes effect on the buttons. It doesn't matter whether I am calling setTitle on a single button or 26 buttons, there is always a delay before the title actually changes.

I read a dated answer mentioning threads when updating the UI, not sure if that is relevant. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the following: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.numericsSelected()
            })  Still no luck though. Interestingly, the delay does not happen in the iOS simulator, only on device.

Comment: I even tried using setNeedsDisplay, but nothing. Getting really desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the reason for the delay.

Every time the setTitle:forState was used the viewWillLayoutSubviews was called, and since I had some custom code in that function it was being run every time the setTitle:forState was used.